# Compile Python code to binary for runing in raspberry pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to compile python3 code to binary using nuitka compiler, but I don't find where to configure de architecture.
Is out there other compiler, or other way to do this.
The final aim is to run the python3 code faster.

I tried de --standalone option of nuitka compiler, but the resulting binary doesn't have the correct format for raspberry pi (3B+)

Comment: Raspberry pi uses ARM64, but Nuitka only supports x86 if I remember.

Comment: Yes I'm afraid you are right, but is there a way to say gcc, the architecture to produce?

Comment: please notice that you need to share a minimal error log file to see what the problem you have exactly right now is not able to reproduce.

Comment: raspbian complains that de format of the binary is not a valid format. But Nuitka can build a directory with the compilation from python to C. ¿Would be a good idea to try to compile C to binary with cc in raspbian?